# Firefox Dev Tools - Blocked Content

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

How can I determine what content Firefox (or Chrome) is blocking (in the case of "mixed" content - http and https). I would of course prefer to not have my content blocked but I can't figure out what exactly Firefox 23 (and Chrome) are blocking to change my code.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox actually has documentation about [mixed content blocking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent). Firefox will display information in the Web Console of the DevTools.

Chrome does the same and displays messages in the Console of the DevTools.

Try playing a video from a `https://youtube.com/` page, for example ;)